# Eclipse Jboss processess

Tags: eclipse, deployment, jboss

I have a couple of questions concerning the way Eclipse 4.3 and JBoss EAP 6.1 work together.

The first would be concerning the Server clean function.  Does it matter if the server is running or not when that function is selected within Eclipse?  I have tried both ways and get no indication one way or the other that it has preformed the task.

The other question concerns the hot deploy. I'm just starting a project so I have errors in my  files, mostly the configuration files.  Everything complies clean.  When Eclipse deploys my war file it does so with something like 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war.  It's always the same name so I can't tell if mu updates have been deployed.

The way I'm currently processing my deploys is to:
1. Undeploy the war file from within the Server Admin page
2. Do a Maven clean
3. Do a project clean
4. Do a war build
5. Redeploy from within the Server Admin page.

So this question would be how to determine if my current changes have been deployed?  Is there a better way of doing it than the way I currently doing it?

Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Maven, you could use the [Maven JBoss Deployment plugin.](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/) This would make the entire process automated. Sometimes the Eclipse integration doesn't work like you expect it to. Additionally, you should see on the JBoss command line console from where you started JBoss, that the old war is undeployed and deployed.

Comment: @codehulhu Thanks I will look for the undeployed and redeploy output.

Comment: @codehulhu I grabbed the Maven plugin, installed it and everything works like I was expected.  First question wasn't answered but checking this one done, because with the plugin, I'm not too concerned about the server clean now.